# Python pyproj converting from WGS84 to Israel Grid IG 05/12

Tags: python, coordinate-system, wgs84, pyproj, israel

Now I see this is duplicate and is answered in
[Pyproj projection 0.5 meter differnce from official results (IGD05/12,IG05/12) Israel Grid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340355/pyproj-projection-0-5-meter-differnce-from-official-results-igd05-12-ig05-12-i)

I am trying to translate coords from WGS84 (file collected using a GPS) to ITM in Israel.
I am testing the code by comparing results with the station points in the official documentation to see if working correctly
and there are small differences.

So what is missing? Where is the mistake?

```
ALON
RESULT:   624087.942N 162790.452E
Expected: 624088.355N 162789.564E
```

My code:

```
from pyproj import Transformer 
stril2012 = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=31.7343936111111 +lon_0=35.2045169444445 +k=1.0000067 +x_0=219529.584 +y_0=626907.39 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-24.002400,-17.103200,-17.844400,-0.33009,-1.852690,1.669690,5.424800 +units=m +no_defs'
stril = stril2012
transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:4326", stril)
#ALON STATION
lat =  (28.569400 / 60 + 42) / 60 + 31
long = (23.921960 / 60 + 36) / 60 + 34
alt = 55.671
res = transformer.transform(lat, long, alt)
print("ALON")
print('RESULT:   {:010.3f}N'.format(res[1]), '{:010.3f}E'.format(res[0]))
print("Expected: 624088.355N 162789.564E")
```

Comment: The transformation you have converts between IGD05/12 and IGD05/12 intermediate according to EPSG. They have [another transformation](https://epsg.org/transformation_9189/WGS-84-to-IG05-12-Intermediate-CRS.html), WGS 84 to IGD05/12 intermediate which is a little bit different. That might match more closely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyproj projection 0.5 meter differnce from official results (IGD05/12,IG05/12) Israel Grid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340355/pyproj-projection-0-5-meter-differnce-from-official-results-igd05-12-ig05-12-i)